# Can I use C3PO/DBCP Connection Pool for one of my website

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm newbie to the connection pool mechanism, I want to implement connection pool mechanism through Hibernate by using C3PO/DBCP Connection pool (Open Source) for my shopping cart website. is there any database performance happens in future??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C3PO would probably work for you (as many other implementations as well) since it is widely used and has been around for a long time.

However:
**If you want to pick the best available pooling library, you need to look around and compare the major competitors.** The best comparison I found (relatively fresh, concise, includes more than 3 libs) is this one:
[Scribd link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/111649850/Connection-Pool-Compare#scribd)

Based on the above (and my own experience) Tomcat JDBC Pooling looks like a better option. From many different aspects:

- good performance
- easy to use
- good quality
- project is actively developed
- etc

Across all these metrics it looks like Tomcat JDBC pooling gives the best consistent results.

Comment: Thanks @Gergely for the nice explanation...By this information  good to go for connection pooling in real-time using C3PO library it's avail/support the hibernate. For this we need to write 5-6 lines of configuration code in hibernate.cfg.xml...

Answer (score 0):

Go for C3P0 as it is actively maintained and is better than DBCP in terms of performance. We had used DBCP in production but found that it was not matured and were having issues so we switched to C3P0 and it is still working like charm.

Comment: I heard some thing like.."both of em are better suitable for dev environment not for production env" ??